# Error message "Unable to create a required folder. Please create the following folder, or set permissions such that it can be created"

Tags: permissions, nautilus

I have created another user for hadoop and when I am trying to login to the new account it is giving me this error:

```
Unable to create a required folder. Please create the following folder, or set permissions such that it can be created:
/home/hduser/.config/nautilus
```

And by clicking close it remains on a blank desktop and also some more errors come: flash plugin is required, etc.

Answer (score 3):

1. Press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F1</kbd> to switch to tty1 console
2. Login
3. Fix permissions for `hduser`

   ```
   sudo chown -R hduser:hduser .
   sudo find /home/hduser/ -type d -exec chmod 750 {} +
   sudo find /home/hduser/ -type f -exec chmod 640 {} +
   ```
4. Press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F7</kbd> to switch back
5. Try login

Comment: Sneetsher, no problem, +1, edited another bit..btw the new avatar is looking good :)